# developing Java EE apps using Eclipse 3.7.1 (Indigo) on  Windows XP, Windows 7 , Ubuntu 11?

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, ubuntu, windows-xp

**What is the best platform for developing Java EE apps using Eclipse 3.7.1 (Indigo) ?
Is it Windows XP, Windows 7 or Ubuntu 11 ??**

from performance perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one that you feel more confortable with. You won't find much difference using Eclipse on any of them.